# stopword removing when using the word2vec

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have been trying word2vec for a while now using the gensim's word2vec library. My question is do I have to remove stopwords from my input text?  Because, based on my initial experimental results, I could see words like 'of', 'when'.. (stopwords) popping up when I do a `model.most_similar('someword')`..?

But I didn't see anywhere referring that stop word removal is necessary with word2vec? Does the word2vec is supposed to handle stop words even if you don't remove them?

What are the must do pre processing things (like for topic modeling, it's almost a must that you should do stopword removal)?

Comment: It all depends on the end-application. What is the ultimate purpose of using the word vectors?

Comment: want to get similar words for a given word using "model.most_similar('someword')"

Comment: Do some evaluation on the models with and without stopwords. To verify your model, check it against synonyms in WordNet. And thne see which model works better. Personally, I think the one with stopwords will work better but showing it empirically through experiment is more important that random guessing.

Comment: I think by removing stop words your results will become better. Its because of frequent words like 'the', 'of', 'is' are not very important until or unless you are dealing some sort of sentence structures ( or syntactic structures). word2vec can learn words those occur in the same context. So, I recommend you to train a model by removing stop words and then train a model without stop words and check which one is performing good.

Comment: @Nomi "word2vec can learn words those occur in the same context." - what's that really mean and how it differs from using a simple probabilistic word collocation finder?

Comment: According to kaggle site: ```To train Word2Vec it is better not to remove stop words because the algorithm relies on the broader context of the sentence in order to produce high-quality word vectors```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personaly I think, removal of stop word will give better results, check [link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html)

Also for topic modeling, you shlould perform preprocessing on the text, following things you must do,

1. Remove of stop words.
2. [Tokenization.](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html)
3. [Stemming and Lemmatization](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html).

Comment: If you are interested in lemmatizer that plays nice with wordnet: try https://gist.github.com/alvations/07758d02412d928414bb

Comment: For standard NLP techniques stop word removal does help. However for the purpose of using Word2Vec the presence of stop words - e.g. 'is', 'of', 'the' also lend significant meaning to the vector representation of words - @Trideep's answer below is more relevant to the question.

Answer (score 52):

Gensim's implementation is based on the original Tomas Mikolov model of word2vec, then it downsamples all frequent words automatically based on frequency.

As stated in [the paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf):

> We show that subsampling of frequent words during training results in
>   a significant speedup (around 2x - 10x), and improves accuracy of the
>   representations of less frequent words.

What it means is that these words are sometimes not considered in the window of the words to be predicted. The sample parameter which defaults to 0.001 is used as a parameter to prune out those words. If you want to remove some specific stopwords which would not be removed based on its frequency, you can do that.

Summary : The result would not make any significant difference if you do stop words removal.

Comment: I would say that this is a more relevant answer to the question, taking into consideration the situation of using the gensim implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned before, it really depends on what you want to do, and the best answer cannot be found in personal opinions, but in experiments. Stop words may play a role in word embedding by associating related words through their relationship to some of those stop words. For example, city names may tend to be more closely associated in a word embedding non only because they are associated with verbs such as "come", "go", "went", "fly", "drive", but also to prepositions such as "to", "from" and "in".

A hypothesis that can be empirically tested is whether the removal of those prepositions decreases the likelihood that those city names will be retrieved together.